# Android Text To Speech Nullpointer Exception

Tags: android

Trying to do a simple text to speech app in android but i am getting NullPointerEception
, i debugged and checked the text is being passed to the tts

[image]

**Below is the code snippets i am using**

```
private TextToSpeech tts;
ArrayList<String> text;


btnPlay = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnPlayText);

                btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        speakText();
                    }

                });



public void speakText() {
        String toSpeak = text.get(0);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toSpeak, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        tts.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        System.out.println();
    }
```

I am passing the text from "text" which is an arraylist containing the data i want to convert and play using tts

> Error is shown at this line MainActivity.java:127
>
> tts.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

**Logcat shows the following**

```
07-20 19:42:20.427: E/AndroidRuntime(19476): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-20 19:42:20.427: E/AndroidRuntime(19476): Process: com.android.speechtest, PID: 19476
07-20 19:42:20.427: E/AndroidRuntime(19476): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-20 19:42:20.427: E/AndroidRuntime(19476):    at com.android.speechtest.MainActivity.speakText(MainActivity.java:127)
07-20 19:42:20.427: E/AndroidRuntime(19476):    at com.android.speechtest.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:111)
07-20 19:42:20.427: E/AndroidRuntime(19476):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4456)
07-20 19:42:20.427: E/AndroidRuntime(19476):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18465)
07-20 19:42:20.427: E/AndroidRuntime(19476):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-20 19:42:20.427: E/AndroidRuntime(19476):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-20 19:42:20.427: E/AndroidRuntime(19476):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-20 19:42:20.427: E/AndroidRuntime(19476):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
07-20 19:42:20.427: E/AndroidRuntime(19476):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-20 19:42:20.427: E/AndroidRuntime(19476):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-20 19:42:20.427: E/AndroidRuntime(19476):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
07-20 19:42:20.427: E/AndroidRuntime(19476):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
07-20 19:42:20.427: E/AndroidRuntime(19476):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-20 19:43:25.763: E/AndroidRuntime(20818): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-20 19:43:25.763: E/AndroidRuntime(20818): Process: com.android.speechtest, PID: 20818
07-20 19:43:25.763: E/AndroidRuntime(20818): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-20 19:43:25.763: E/AndroidRuntime(20818):    at com.android.speechtest.MainActivity.speakText(MainActivity.java:127)
07-20 19:43:25.763: E/AndroidRuntime(20818):    at com.android.speechtest.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:111)
07-20 19:43:25.763: E/AndroidRuntime(20818):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4456)
07-20 19:43:25.763: E/AndroidRuntime(20818):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18465)
07-20 19:43:25.763: E/AndroidRuntime(20818):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-20 19:43:25.763: E/AndroidRuntime(20818):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-20 19:43:25.763: E/AndroidRuntime(20818):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-20 19:43:25.763: E/AndroidRuntime(20818):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
07-20 19:43:25.763: E/AndroidRuntime(20818):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-20 19:43:25.763: E/AndroidRuntime(20818):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-20 19:43:25.763: E/AndroidRuntime(20818):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
07-20 19:43:25.763: E/AndroidRuntime(20818):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
07-20 19:43:25.763: E/AndroidRuntime(20818):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-20 19:44:29.289: E/ActivityThread(21489): Performing pause of activity that is not resumed: {com.android.speechtest/com.android.speechtest.MainActivity}
07-20 19:44:29.289: E/ActivityThread(21489): java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing pause of activity that is not resumed: {com.android.speechtest/com.android.speechtest.MainActivity}
07-20 19:44:29.289: E/ActivityThread(21489):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3084)
07-20 19:44:29.289: E/ActivityThread(21489):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3072)
07-20 19:44:29.289: E/ActivityThread(21489):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3050)
07-20 19:44:29.289: E/ActivityThread(21489):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:139)
07-20 19:44:29.289: E/ActivityThread(21489):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1221)
07-20 19:44:29.289: E/ActivityThread(21489):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-20 19:44:29.289: E/ActivityThread(21489):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-20 19:44:29.289: E/ActivityThread(21489):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
07-20 19:44:29.289: E/ActivityThread(21489):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-20 19:44:29.289: E/ActivityThread(21489):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-20 19:44:29.289: E/ActivityThread(21489):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
07-20 19:44:29.289: E/ActivityThread(21489):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
07-20 19:44:29.289: E/ActivityThread(21489):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You haven't initialized "text". So text.getText(0) is null.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/2jDQN.png its not null,else i wouldnt get the text in the variable toSpeak

Comment: @ViVekH, see my answer, this code snippet works well;)!

Comment: @André.C.S i tried implementing the code you gave me, http://pastebin.com/5j891McN  but it didnt work

Comment: @ViVekH,you seen it? [Android Speech To Text Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-speech-to-text-tutorial/)

Comment: @ViVekH, I think you need to see some more things, which is not being abordao the link you followed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure the `tts` has been initialized first

```
tts = new TextToSpeech(context, onInitListener);
```

You can simply check it in `speakText` method as follow

```
public void speakText() {
    ...
    if(tts != null) {
        tts.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    } else {
        Log.e("YOUR_TAG", "TextToSpeech Null");
    }
}
```

Comment: i was refering the code from here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_text_to_speech.htm

tts = new TextToSpeech(context, onInitListener);

how do i pass onInitListener?
or may i ask what do i write for onInitListener?

Comment: The OnInitListener will be invoked after the completion of the TextToSpeech engine initialization, from the link in your comment you can do something like this >> tts = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
   @Override
   public void onInit(int status) {
       // do whatever you want
   }
}
);

Comment: here's my enitre code http://pastebin.com/5j891McN , i am actually doing speech to text and then text to speech and text to speech is crashing

Comment: In `onCreate` method after this statement `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` add the following statement `tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);`

Comment: depending on the code you have posted on your second comment you need to add this `tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);` after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` because your activity already implemented OnInitListener, so you do need to create a new one :)

Comment: Or if it's works with you you can just remove the implementation of OnInitListener from your activity and continue using this way :)

Answer (score 0):

compare your code with this sample to see if you do not forget to do som step :)

see more here: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-text-to-speech-tutorial/

```
public class AndroidTextToSpeechActivity extends Activity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private TextToSpeech tts;
    private Button btnSpeak;
    private EditText txtText;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);

        btnSpeak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);

        txtText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtText);

        // button on click event
        btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                speakOut();
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Don't forget to shutdown tts!
        if (tts != null) {
            tts.stop();
            tts.shutdown();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {

        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

            int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);

            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                    || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
            } else {
                btnSpeak.setEnabled(true);
                speakOut();
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
        }

    }

    private void speakOut() {

        String text = txtText.getText().toString();

        tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you not missing the initialization of ArrayList text?
Maybe try with:

```
text.add("apple");
text.add("android");
```

first. Then try with:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    text.add((EditText) findViewById(R.id.btnPlayText));
    speakText();
}
```

Comment: the data is being passed to tts
refer http://i.stack.imgur.com/2jDQN.png

so i am getting data from arraylist successfully